# Why would mqtt messages not be delivered

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

I'm using paho on android 4.3, talking to the hosted eclipse mosquitto server at `m2m.eclipse.org`. I have the client wrapped in a service, and am using the `AlarmManager` to send keep-alive messages to the server. I have a separate client (just using the mqtt httbridge, or another android device using paho) that sends messages to the topic my service is listening to.

everything works swimmingly... until it doesn't. at some point, my android service stops receiving messages. keep-alives keep sending, everyhting seems fine, but messages aren't getting through. i haven't been able to replicate this behavior on a local instance of mosquitto, which makes me think it's some sort of configuration on the eclipse side, but would aprpeaciate any pointers.

QoS is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using QoS 1 or 2?

[From MQTT specs](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/Cclient/qos.html) QoS 0 is **At most once**: *The message is delivered at most once, or it may not be delivered at all. Its delivery across the network is not acknowledged. The message is not stored. The message could be lost if the client is disconnected, or if the server fails. QoS0 is the fastest mode of transfer. It is sometimes called "fire and forget".*

Comment: yes, with the same effect. the QoS issue would make sense as a culprit if delivery were intermittent. It's not. At some point, it just stops.

Comment: Do you see a disconnection in the logs? You must subscribe to topics again every time you reconnect. What happens if you setup a second subscriber (eg. a small app on your computer)?

Comment: this only happens when i'm talking to the freebie eclipse m2m server, so i don't see the server logs. nothing in my logs indicate any problems

Comment: Does this also happens with other clients?